# Как остановить эффект прокрутки (перескок) после перетаскивания?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Я делаю канбан-доску для работы с заявками. Естественно статусов много и по этому пришлось прикрутить скролл. Пробую прикрутить [smoothDivScroll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440239/11183)

Таблица  выглядит так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код js такой:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("div.scroller-right-content").smoothDivScroll({
  //прокрутка с помощью колеса мыши
  //по всем направлениям (не все мыши имеют такую возможность)
  mousewheelScrolling: false,
  manualContinuousScrolling: false, //Бесконечный цикл
  touchScrolling:true,
  /*
  "" - пустая строка сделает стрелки для прокрутки невидимыми всегда.
  hover - сделает стрелки для прокрутки видимым, только при наведении мыши на скроллер.
  onStart - делает стрелки для прокрутки видимыми n секунд
  always - стрелки для прокрутки видны все время.
  */
        visibleHotSpotBackgrounds:"always",
        /*
        если предыдущее значение onStart
        через столько миллисекунд стрелки исчезнут                        
        */
  hotSpotsVisibleTime: 2000,
        // автозапуск при загрузке страницы
        // уберите эту строку, если Вам это не нужно
        //autoScrollingMode:onStart,
}); 


$( "<?=$options?>" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".suppilo_status_block",
  cancel: ".title_status_suppilo, .nav, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu, .divider-d, .border-b",
  items: 'li', // Указывает какие элементы в группе могут быть отсортированы. 
  handle: '.drag-item-suppilo-status', //Указывает элемент, при щелчке на который начнется перетаскивание. 
  helper:'original', // Устанавливает вид элемента помощника  original или clone
  opacity:1, // прозрачность перетаскиваемого элемента
  cursor: 'n-resize', // вид курсора при нажатии
  revert: 'true', // эффект вставляния перетаскиваемого элемента
  placeholder:"ui-state-highlight",
  start: function (){
    $('.scrollWrapper').css('overflow','visible'); // меняем на visible чтобы не крутилось, когда берем элемент. 
  },
  beforeStop: function (event, ui){
    $('.scrollWrapper').css('overflow','hidden');  // меняем на hidden возобновить прокрутку
    var id_status = ui.item.parent().data('id-status');
    var id_order = ui.item.data('id');
    console.log(''+ui.item.data('id')+' из '+ui.item.parent().data('id-status')+'');
  //... код ajax сохранить
  } 

}).disableSelection();


});
```

**Описание:** Чтобы отключить прокрутку вовремя перетаскивания, пришлось (кустарно) в момент начала перетаскивания изменять css значение области `.scrollWrapper` прокрутки с overflow:hidden на overflow:visible (в коде подписано где это), только после этого можно перетаскивать в нужную область. Пока скроллер не крутишь все работает нормально, все меняется когда немного прокрутишь вправо...

**Проблема:** Когда я например прокрутил слайдер чуть-чуть вбок, начал перетаскивать элемент, то после отпускания перетаскиваемого элемента происходит перескок на начальную видимость таблицы. Это проблема. Перескока не должно быть, после перетаскивания скроллер должен включиться и остаться на месте. Как решить, может можно останавливать скроллер на время перетаскивания как-то иначе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте останавливать скроллер путем отключения его экш-скролл блоков

```
.disabled { display: none !important }
```

-

```
start: function (){
    $('.scrollingHotSpotLeft').addClass('disabled');
    $('.scrollingHotSpotRight').addClass('disabled');
  }

beforeStop: function (event, ui){
    $('.scrollingHotSpotLeft').removeClass('disabled');
    $('.scrollingHotSpotRight').removeClass('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Почти помогло, но работает только первый раз, потом хватаешь второй элемент, начинает опять прокручивать слайдер, хотя все исчезает. Так же если прокрутить немного в сторону и начать перетаскивание, то проблема продолжается.